# How to put Image in Custom Keyboard?

Tags: objective-c, xcode6, custom-keyboard, ios8-extension

I am a iOS application developer. I am now working with iOS8 custom keyboard.
I have created a custom keyboard with custom view. I can put their button and view.
I am unable to put image or animated image(GIF) over there. Can any one please help me to make this done.

Comment: Have you got any solution for GIF images in custom keyboard? If you have any solution then i need your help.

Comment: Hi guys, Have u find any solution??

Answer (score 0):

You can't use GIF images in custom keyboard. Add the png images into custom keyboard target directory ( Not your application directory ).

After adding the images, Check in custom keyboard target -> Build Phases -> Copy Bundle Resources. If images not added here, add the images using + button

Comment: How can you say that we can not use GIF images in custom keyboard? Is there any proof or link?

Comment: GIF can definitely be use in custom keyboard. You can refer to this useful category methods which allow you to load GIF images.

https://github.com/mayoff/uiimage-from-animated-gif